# Excel vba formula.local error

Tags: excel, vba

`IF(ISBLANK(" & variable & "!G2);" & """""" & ";IF(ISERROR(DATE(YEAR(" & variable & "!G2);MONTH(" & variable  & "!G2)+6;DAY(" & variable  & "!G2)));" & """""" & "; (DATE(YEAR(" & variable & "!G2);MONTH(" & variable & "!G2)+6;DAY(" & variable & "!G2))))"`

`variable` is a name of variable which contains name of sheet.

I get: "application-defined or object-defined error.

Can someone help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use this one (removed `(` before `DATE`):

`Range("A1").FormulaLocal = "=IF(ISBLANK(" & variable & "!G2);" & """""" & ";IF(ISERROR(DATE(YEAR(" & variable & "!G2);MONTH(" & variable & "!G2)+6;DAY(" & variable & "!G2)));" & """""" & "; DATE(YEAR(" & variable & "!G2);MONTH(" & variable & "!G2)+6;DAY(" & variable & "!G2))))"`

Answer (score 0):

The main problem is that you are using semi-colons instead of commas in the if statement.

Initially I thought you were trying to do this in the worksheet, in which case you would have needed to use INDIRECT().

However on re-reading your question I realised you were trying to build a formula string in VBA.

The formula string you are building is not the correct syntax.  For example you use ";" instead of ",".  I also think you have the wrong number of brackets.

If I were you I would debug this by doing something like:

```
sFormula = "IF(ISBLANK(" & variable & "!G2);" & """""" & ";IF(ISERROR(DATE(YEAR(" & variable & "!G2);MONTH(" & variable & "!G2)+6;DAY(" & variable & "!G2)));" & """""" & "; (DATE(YEAR(" & variable & "!G2);MONTH(" & variable & "!G2)+6;DAY(" & variable & "!G2))))"
Debug.Print sFormula
```

And then pasting the resulting string into the spreadsheet and see if it works, and edit as appropriate.

Comment: using commas `,` or semicolons `;` in `FormulaLocal` depends on the local settings on the PC.